# How to query dates in SAS

Tags: date, sas

I need to export some data from SAS to CSV, so that I can move it to a SQL Server and load it into there.  (The servers can't see each other.)

In the data is a field with the following definitions:

- Type = Number
- Length = 8
- Format = DATETIME18.

For now I'm just trying to see how many records exist in a date range:

```
proc sql;

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM BNA_BASE.base_agent_bna_cust_date
WHERE bna_outcome_ts >= '04Jun12:00:00:00'd
  AND bna_outcome_ts <  '11Jun12:00:00:00'd
;

quit;
```

But I always get `0`, even though I can see in the table that there are records which match what I thought I was querying, such as `06JUN12:12:42:57`.

Can anyone point out my stupid mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should have used `dt` not just `d`...

```
WHERE bna_outcome_ts >= '04Jun12:00:00:00'dt
  AND bna_outcome_ts <  '11Jun12:00:00:00'dt
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Dems answer is to use the datepart() function,

e.g.

```
where datepart(bna_outcome_ts) >= '04jun2012'd
and datepart(bna_outcoume_ts) < '11jun2012'd
```